# Python threads and scipy.interpolate.interp2d

Tags: python, multithreading, scipy, anaconda

I have this class that creates random 2d maps. The following code does nothing except creating the map since I've stripped it down to isolate the bug:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

class CRelevanceMap:

    def __init__(self):
        self.relmap = self._create_map(4, 6)

    def _create_map(self, iters, granularity):
        x = np.linspace(0,1,granularity)
        z = np.random.randn(granularity, granularity) / granularity

        for k in range(iters):
            f = interp2d(x,x,z)
            granularity *= 2
            x = np.linspace(0,1,granularity)
            z = f(x, x) + np.random.randn(granularity, granularity) / granularity

        if np.isnan( z[0][0] ):
            print('FAILED', flush=True)

        return z
```

It worked well for many hours in a single-threaded program. Now I'm trying to use it with multi-threading:

```
import time, threading, relevancemap

class Mythread(threading.Thread):
    stop_signal = False

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop_signal:
            self.rmap = relevancemap.CRelevanceMap()
            time.sleep(0) 

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_signal = True

#-- main

mt = [Mythread() for i in range(32)]
for t in mt:
      t.start()

time.sleep(3)

for t in mt:
      t.stop()
for t in mt:
      t.join()
```

and I keep getting the "FAILED" error at random. 
Basically, it seems that the evaluation of the function "f" returned by interp2d sometimes returns all NaN. I'm quite new to Python, so I don't understand where the problem is. To the best of my understanding, threads are not sharing any data so no locks or other sync stuff should be needed. Each one has its own instances of CRelevanceMap which shouldn't interfere with others... but seems I'm wrong.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Testing environments:

- Python 3.6.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) on Windows 10 Laptop, i7-5500U 8Gb RAM
- Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc. on Linux server, dual Xeon E5-2660 256Gb RAM

Problem is much less frequent on the linux server, but still it rarely happens.